# Gestor de replicacion de base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, webservice, mariadb

Me pidieron hacer un proyecto para la clase de sistemas distribuidos el cual es un punto de venta normal pero con la particularidad de que la base de datos va a estar replicada en 3 ordenadores distintos y se nos encargo específicamente que el sistema debe seguir funcionando mientras una de las tres computadoras siga encendida por lo que se va a probar todas las combinaciones de PCs encendidas y apagadas para probar que este punto se cumpla.

El sistema ya esta hecho con una sola base de datos, solo falta replicarla, lo cual no es complicado, lo que me parece complicado y es por lo que estoy aqui es para saber como es que se tiene que hacer para que el sistema haga peticiones a la computadora que este encendida, es decir, en el proyecto yo hago una petición con ajax a un web service en java el cual hace los querys a la única base de datos pero como podre hacer que el sistema siga funcionando si la computadora a la que le hace query esta apagada que pueda hacer query a la siguiente computadora (porque son 3) con la base de forma rápida y autónoma? que aunque el nodo maestro este apagado se sigan actualizando los esclavos?

El profesor nos dio solo unas cuantas pistas, menciono que hay gestores de bases de datos que lo hacen (literal eso fue todo lo que nos dijo) y que debíamos investigar como lograrlo, he leído un poco pero no encuentro algo que me ayude ya que ni siquiera se como es que debería buscarlo

Espero y puedan ayudarme, cualquier cosa es buena, solo necesito un camino por donde empezar

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Te paso una solución - [esta](http://basesdedatosues.blogspot.com/2011/06/bases-de-datos-distribuidas-con-mysql.html), que es la primera entrada de la búsqueda "base de datos distribuida mysql" en google y he tardado un minuto en encontrarla. Te debe servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero no es una distribucion de db normal lo que ocupo, mysql no soporta una replicacion multi maestro-maestro que es algo asi lo que ocupo, encontre que lo que necesito se llama clustering, ya estoy trabajando con eso esperando que funcione